# Gutenberg text field validation

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, block-editor

I have been searching for ages but can't seem to find an exact method on how to perform text input validation when building custom blocks. I saw that for `TextControl` inputs you can just pass the `required` prop but that doesn't seem to do anything ie: when I click on update or publish etc. it carries on like normal.

```
<TextControl
  label="Title"
  value={title}
  onChange={(title) => setAttributes({ title })}
  required
/>
```

The same issue would arise for RichText components as well.

Comment: `TextControl` has no concept of publishing or updating, or even posts, it's a 100% _generic_ text control, you can even use it outside of WordPress. That component is unaware of the block editor by the design, and implements a dumb wrapper around text inputs for HTML with some additional helpful things. It is not a full validation suite for block attributes, much in the same way that a small plastic pipe is not a full building plumbing system. You also can't _force_ your block to have a title, as anybody could edit the title out of the markup and you still have to handle that

Comment: And block attributes have a [type and enum validations](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-attributes/#type-validation), and for extended validation, you can use a custom JS function which will validate the input value prior to setting the specific attribute. E.g. `onChange={ ( title ) => /[a-z]+/i.test( title ) && setAttributes({ title }) }` (untested) .. So validate upon setting the attribute as opposed to upon saving the post.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I will have to try and get creative :)